# errors when trying to retrieve information from spotify api

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch, spotify

I have been working on an app that uses the Spotify API and I just can't get the data retrieval part to work. I keep getting `403` errors when I send `GET` requests. Here is my code for the method in concern:

```
const fetchTopSongs = async (accessToken) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks?time_range=${timeRange}&limit=25`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      setTopSongs(data.items)
      console.log(topSongs);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Is there an issue with the function here, or is the problem somewhere else, like my `getAccessToken` function? I tested things and it seems fine, but the only trouble comes when I try to send a get request. If anyone is experienced in Spotify or axios/fetch error handling, please help, thanks!

Comment: Check if [this](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/1118) helps. You need to use proper scope and permissions

Comment: The exact same question was asked (and answered) at the [Spotify Community](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-for-Developers/403-error-on-GET-v1-me-top-tracks/td-p/5603611).

Comment: The problem is: OP was using Client Credentials.